# FB Login button not changing to 'Logout" upon user login for FB app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, facebook-login

I'm a junior developer and trying to follow instructions provided in quickstart for FB login (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/295265115675132/fb-login/quickstart/), but have to make some changes in order to be compliant with React framework. Using my current code, a defined test user for the app is able to login successfully, but login button doesn't change to 'logout' (as expected). I need to actually use the logout function on facebook.com to do so. Additionally, I would like to redirect to another page (https://localhost:3000/#/initiateWorkflow) upon successful login by using the 'useHistory' hook for react router. Adding data-onlogin="history.push('/initiateWorkflow')" attribute to the button makes the hook/function unreachable. Error message: "sdk.js?hash=febd5fc202fe1dbfcb2832126bced2e5&ua=modern_es6:63 Uncaught TypeError: history.push is not a function
at eval (eval at  (eval at a (sdk.js?hash=febd5fc202fe1dbfcb2832126bced2e5&ua=modern_es6:183)), :1:9)..."

I'm sure there's a better way to redirect. Please advise.

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
        FB.init({
          appId: '295265115675132',
          cookie: true,
          xfbml: true,
          version: 'v11.0'
        })

        FB.AppEvents.logPageView()
      }
      ;(function (d, s, id) {
        var js,
          fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0]
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
          return
        }
        js = d.createElement(s)
        js.id = id
        js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js'
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs)
      })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')
    </script>
  </body>
  <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Login container:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useHistory, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = () => {
  const history = useHistory()

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>
        Please ensure you are logged into your Facebook account to get started.
      </h1>
      <div className='row'>
        <div
          className='fb-login-button'
          data-width=''
          data-size='large'
          // data-button-type='continue_with'
          data-layout='rounded'
          data-auto-logout-link='true'
          data-use-continue-as='true'
         // data-onlogin="history.push('/initiateWorkflow')"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Open to suggestions, anybody?

Answer (score 0):

So solved this on my own using the following blog post and implementing the author's approach: [blog post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/10/25/react-facebook-login-tutorial-example#index-html)

Thanks a million to Jason Watmore!